# MVC Routing / HostHeader does not work when I use RequireHttps

Tags: model-view-controller, routes, hostheader

I'm currently experiencing an issue whereby my MVC site is not responding correctly using IIS 6.

I've setup a url as http://mysite.co.uk which automatically redirects to the correct MVC home page. As the site contains sensitive information I have added the [RequireHttps] attribute to each controller class to automatically redirect the browser to an https url of https://mysite.co.uk which works correctly.

When I access the site as http://**www**.mysite.co.uk the site correctly redirects to https://**www**.mysite.co.uk/Default.aspx but it then responds with

> Bad Request (Invalid Hostname)

It looks like any time I use **www.** as part of the url it fails to respond but I have a hostheader setup as www.mysite.co.uk under the IIS website. Is there anything in particular I need to do to make MVC understand the www. part of the url in terms of routing?

Thanks,
Brian.

Answer (score 0):

IIS 6 doesn't add ssl host headers as you think it would. see my article at:

http://completedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/06/multiple-host-headers-ssl-and-wcf.html